# OpenSSL PHP Function doesn't work

Tags: php, security, openssl, rsa, der

I'm looking for days how to translate this command to OpenSLL php function:

```
$ openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in aaa010101aaa_CSD_01.key -out AAA010101AAA.key.pem
Enter Password: a0123456789
```

This work perfect, but I can't (I don't know) use the correct function of PHP OpenSSL
http://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.openssl.php

I have made this for .cer working perfect:

```
command : openssl x509 -inform DER -outform PEM -in aaa010101aaa_CSD_01.cer -out AAA010101AAA.cer.pem
```

PHP equivalent:

```
function der2pem($der_data) {
    $pem = chunk_split(base64_encode($der_data), 64, "\n");
    $pem = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n".$pem."-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
    return $pem;
}

$fp = fopen("llaves/aaa010101aaa_CSD_01.cer", "r");
$priv_key = fread($fp, 8192);
fclose($fp);

echo der2pem($priv_key);
```

It's perfect, giving it to me the PEM. But doesn't work for the .key, just for the .cer, I obtain on OpenSSL this for .key using the funcion on PHP:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The same function on php give me:

```
-----BEGIN----- 
MIICxjBABgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wMzAbBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwDgQIgkLCyAP9+nQCAggA MBQGCCqGSIb3DQMHBAgTJc/0zgL+tASCAoBHumtbuHsY5IevnUwr1Ha5P+S3RpVS 6iYvoOvKs5L6bPE+fjCkLxset0e68NcyXDw3WO/qzfGkFVGBnC90gekWUiS7/2pf ltPeKjo8Fw7T4CgVWhtnVdPZmJWihY52FuIQ2HuyQYzH8K/SnjYP4GBkJKpdPCjy JNzjspfJPoOlfdOkj7URwvKH5RjsLGYkopjtdaqxS2pFfz6PPCSiFMn+Jo9Vkjwv 3d1b3X2SoYuYhV2g3XgHWHBQNqoas8Blhcw8OYNlntxcaNnx3Eb9YcCWSmNj7l+c pibvosXzEqVoat6PsJyUVzJQZBao15PnI438qomkprsCy6EvFSSXuIunMH7nVIGH gcS0TRxYpXPHY3cdQOdsJtxb4Ny1aCJqLQkHs2jbiLZ5mu+rmQUil3tLxfRd4Bje AYA3T1e5VVVha97BmNQVTbNfxj9wWvkmrearxJXTvvnML4f0ma830S/1AGmCGLb/ A2KlqHq9RxqJn1SdOuYQbcQTeGe/JRVOaJVGUKxJ2vbwjB/35cmGNLKYj4faZZgy jYpC3BqVeDcPGlPuMnoNkgrBfLDgDX+JV6tqqT2uMo76Wp6xYKmM41jkO1IAWpHR /R7d3aG2psL0wKkFSEXWxhX3SRLdurVcFLv6E6bEPHqHJR4QrvF2OUwpDhOZz9F/ Lz935gz5MQNRuVRtAVBAa2ZmjRbdCboL/qiL2MKibZLNRmKy3dqRdPOmnlKKBR8d cYQc4YwRm5dWuObO2tY68R4H43g7shw+POKSzvSPhAkzRRGExONVDJ6Zg/0iAUNe 0xYlsqKJyCJ1fg/b1AuFyyAnOhCO9ywUGiK7t92pZRgmwxEfVBDRNcbA 
-----END -----
```

Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, according to this, ¿Is there a way to use OpenSSL on safe_mode_exec_dir ?, my server is under safemode, reason for this thread to avoid using exec().

Thanks : )

Comment: You lost me on the last part. What PHP code did you use to generate the last example?

Answer (score -1):

There's a library that allows just that. It is called [Chilkat2](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/php.asp). I used it to do the same in Python without console.
Right now I'm trying to remove this dependency in [my library](https://github.com/guillermo11bq/sat-descarga-masiva-python) because it's closed source and it can't be installed through package managers, it must be installed manually with the website instructions.

It works pretty well, however, so here's how you would do it, assuming you have the .key file, the password, and Chilkat2 PHP Extension installed:

```
include("chilkat_9_5_0.php"); //whatever version you download

privateKey = new CkPrivateKey();
privateKey.LoadPkcs8EncryptedFile('path/to/private.key',password)

pemString = privateKey.getPkcs8Pem()
```

Note: I created this code with the [documentation](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/phpCkPrivateKeyRef.html), but I have never used Chilkat2 with PHP.

Comment: What do you mean? If the function names seem funny to you it is becuse the guy uses the same format in all ported versions of his library. But I took this process straight out from the documentation and it works the same way in the python version.

Comment: I mean, the code that you have written here is not PHP.

Comment: And I mean, why do you think so?